# How to display submenu in Reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am making an application in reactjs with reactstrap (Bootstrap) css framework. And I am trying to make a navbar with menu and sub menu (Only one level of sub menu).

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-navbartoggler-example-fmbvpa)**

And I am working to achieve this in a single `JS` file,

**Example.JS**

```
<UncontrolledButtonDropdown>
   <DropdownToggle caret size="md">
      Menu 1
   </DropdownToggle>

   <DropdownMenu>
      <span> Sub Menu 1 </span>
      <DropdownItem>Sub Menu 1.1</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Sub Menu 1.2</DropdownItem>

      <span> Sub Menu 2 </span>
      <DropdownItem>Sub Menu 2.1</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Sub Menu 2.2</DropdownItem>
   </DropdownMenu>
</UncontrolledButtonDropdown>
```

I am in the need of above part alone.

I am listing a dropdown menu on click of toggler button and there I am having `Menu 1` as a dropdown.

For normal view let it be as it is but for **responsive** view the menu should be displayed in an order.

So it will be looking like,

The navbar with dropdown menu

[image]

And on click on the parent menu (**Menu 1**), the **Sub Menu 1**
 part needs to be displayed like,

The dropdown menu listing sub menus separately in another view

[image]

So here you can look that Menu will be displayed first and on click on the menu the sub menu needs to be displayed separately on another view.

It is okay if anyone could help me to do the same in pure bootstrap **without jquery**.

Answer (score 0):

For the dropdown menu to be responsive, I don't think you can use the reactstrap library. However, you can use the bootstrap library to render a responsive dropdown. Follow this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/dropdowns/#responsive-alignment).

Comment: Can you provide solution in bootstrap way to achieve the same without jquery? As it is reactjs application, we should not use jquery inside it but bootstrap comes with jquery..

Comment: In that case you can use the react-bootstrap library. You can use the dropdown directions like this https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/#drop-directions

Comment: Sorry this is not my expectation.. I am done with dropdowns but if I click the menu then the submenu needs to be displayed..